# Shared Hosting folder access to Hosting provider

Tags: web-hosting, file-permissions, shared-hosting

I've website running on a shared hosting account and I allow users to upload Images and I store them on the server in a folder that I've access to.

My concern is whether that folder containing image files is accessible to the Hosting Provider or not?

If accessible how can I disallow hosting provider by accessing the folder.

Comment: If it's their server, they can do what they want with it. End of converstion. If it's your server (i.e. Colocated) then things change.

Comment: Shared hosting accounts aren't really topical here.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer:  Yes.

It is their server and they can do whatever and see whatever they want.  There is no way you, as a user, would be able to disallow access to the folder.

An alternative for you if you are concerned with it is to download a freeware web server and host your image folder off of your own server.  That way you have complete and full access to the contents and to the permissions of the server.

Comment: I'll be happy if you could suggest me some examples of freeware web servers. You meant to say that the system that is acting as webserver will always be online?

Comment: @hungrycoder yes...if the server is powered off how can users access it? Apache, IIS, and ngix are the three main web servers, although IIS needs a Windows host.

Comment: Webserver SOFTWARE to be more specific and the ones tombull89 listed are a few.  There are thousands out there and a Google or download.com search would yield these results.